# How to tell if a file exists always returns false but I can load it via image tag

Tags: objective-c, xcode

In xcode, I have create a folder called IMAGES and copied all of the images I will be using into that folder.

I am updating a table using the following code to insert the image:

```
   NSString *picName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.jpg", [[theemplyees objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"EmpNo"]];

   cell.empPicture.image = [UIImage imageNamed:picName];
```

Note the no location needing supplied.  What I want to do is, if a users picture does not exist in the directly, then set the image to a default image.  Such as:

```
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

//Set image
NSString *imagePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:picName];

//Check if the image exists at a given path
BOOL imageExists = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:imagePath];

//If the image doesn't exists download it.
if (!imageExists)
{
    picName = @"nopicture.jpg";
}
```

The problem is, using the above, it ALWAYS says the files don't exist.  NONE!  Grrr
So am i placing the files in the wrong location?  I attempted to create a directory called Resources and place them there but still didn;t work.

Any help is greatly appreciated.  Thanks in advance for any and all help.

Geo...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing will be in the app's `Documents` directory unless you store something there during runtime. The `Documents` directory and the app's resource bundle are two completely different things.

If you created a folder in Xcode for your images, those images are still stored in the app's resource bundle, not the `Documents` folder.

The `UIImage imageNamed:` method only looks in the resource bundle.