# Where to place files for later access via code?

Tags: ios, objective-c, filesystems

I am currently working on an app that will display certain image files.  As times goes by, more images will be added via a NSURL get process, which means I will want to save them in the same location so when I look to load them, they are all in the same directory.

The app will also allow for removing of these files.  I had originally though I could just place them in the documents directory but I do not see a way to do this via xcode.  I know I can add them to the bundles directory on compile, but I read that you cannot save items via code to the bundle directory.  I had thought about on load, copying the files to the documents directory but that seems redundant as I would have two copies of some files.

I am sure I am missing something very simple here but how/where do I save the images and then be able to add/remove from save location?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I'm confused. You've already shown you know how to do this in a previous question of yours http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15731396/how-to-tell-if-a-file-exists-always-returns-false-but-i-can-load-it-via-image-ta

Comment: You save them in your file system, as RazorSharp indicates.  You do need to be aware that image files downloaded by URL would generally NOT be considered to be "critical data" and should be stored in the cache directory, with provisions to re-download from your server if the system deletes the files.

Comment: Yes I know how to see if the file already exists, but what I am wanting to do is place all image files in a directory where I can add more or remove them.  If I don't include them in the bundle on first install, they are never on device.  I want to add them to a directory that I can manage right from the start.  Make sense?

Comment: Then put them in a directory!  You just have to observe Apple's rules about WHERE that directory can be.  (Note that the bundle itself is read-only, and your app cannot add files to or remove files from the bundle.)

Comment: Okay then how do I add my own folder?  I know I can right click and say add Files...do I select Create Folder Reference for any added folders?  If so, how would i then access those files?  As in where would the location be?  

 NSString *libraryPath = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) lastObject];

Comment: @George Folders created in Xcode will not show up in your app's folder. Please read over the link I provided in my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you need to read over and understand [this documentation from Apple](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/FileSystemProgrammingGUide/FileSystemOverview/FileSystemOverview.html). It explains how apps save and store files, where they're stored, how to store them, among other things. It sounds like you'll need to store your files in the Documents directory. Here's Apple's description of the Document's Directory:

> Use this directory to store critical user documents and app data files. Critical data is any data that cannot be recreated by your app, such as user-generated content.
>   The contents of this directory can be made available to the user through file sharing. The contents of this directory are backed up by iTunes.

Files stored here can be saved, read, overwritten, renamed, deleted, etc. by your app. When your app is installed on a device, the documents directory is automatically created - however it is your job to fill it (or not).

You cannot set certain files to be moved to the Documents Directory in Xcode. You can move them there on your first launch from your bundle like this:

```
//Start the process on the background thread to avoid clogging up the UI (esp. on the first launch)
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, (unsigned long)NULL), ^(void) {
    //Create File Ptah
    NSString *filePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"FileName.ext"];
    //Only copy file if it doesn't already exist
    if ([fileManager fileExistsAtPath:filePath] == NO) {
           //Get file path of file in bundle
           NSString *resourcePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"FileName" ofType:@"ext"];
           //Copy the bundle file to the documents directory (we can't move it because the contents of the bundle are read-only)
           [fileManager copyItemAtPath:resourcePath toPath:filePath error:&error];
    }
});
```

Comment: Okay I understand but by copying from the bundle to the documents directory, that in reality is meaning the files is in the system twice.  I just thought there might be a way to create my own directory and then push that up.  Then I could add/remove as needed.

Comment: @George The content's of your app's bundle cannot be modified - it is read-only. You also cannot create a directory (as far as I'm aware) at the root level of your app's folder. Something else it seems that you misunderstand (from your comments on the question) is that you cannot create these directories in Xcode - they are automatically created by iOS when the app is installed. I'm not sure why you need a separate directory - the documents directory is read/write and can be modified at any time by either your app or the user.

Comment: Thanks I guess the only thing I was thinking was:  If files I want to access are in bundle, and after first install, I will want to either add or remove some files, it just seemed odd that I would have to COPY the files form bundle to documents directory...thus doubling the size of the app as there are now TWO sets of the original files.

Comment: @George Ah yes! I have come across that issue myself. There really isn't a way around it. You could however (providing the files were not scripts or code or anything) download the files from a server into your documents directory on the first load. However, that presents other issues. Or if they aren't complicated files, you could generate them programatically. Anyway, good luck! Remember to mark this answer as accepted if it helped. Just tick the checkmark next to it.

Comment: Will do.  Thanks.  Just seems silly that there isn't a way around this.

Comment: It isn't silly - it's by design. Resources in your bundle are readonly. The bundle is cryptographically signed, so any changes to it means that the signature check fails. You don't really want your users to end up with broken software because they saved a file to the bundle. It's quite common to move resources out of the bundle into the file sandbox. e.g. with Core Data apps - you sometimes initialise your store from a copy in the bundle.

Comment: Ok, maybe silly isn't the right word.  I just thought there would be a way to add files to a directory that can be manipulated without having to have duplicate files in the app.  Thx to everyone who replied.